# Convert XML to JSON while retaining html tags

Tags: java, xml-to-json

I have XML documents need to convert to JSON using org.json as per code snippet below. But the problem with this approach it does not retain HTML tags in original XML, for example the XML text
`<abstract>the max power density was 582.4 mW/m<sup>2</sup>. After temperature decreasing</abstract>` is mapped to

`"abstract":"the max power density was 582.4 mW/m. After temperature decreasing"`. Any idea how to retain the HTML tags?

```
try(FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File("json.json")))
        {
            JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(new StringReader(xmlRec));
            String jsonString = json.toString(4);
            System.out.println("JSON str:  " + jsonString);
            out.write(jsonString);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why the json parser would remove any xml/html tags, for org.json this is just another `String`. Are you certain that it gets removed?

Comment: Since HTML tags is a subset of XML tags, it will not be an easy task. You will have to identify every single tag you want untouched and then manipulate them in a way that you can revert, while still being valid XML

Comment: What is `xmlRec` ? Your code snippet seems incomplete

Comment: Yes, I am certain it removes the HTML tag. I had abstract value in XML "max power density was 582.4 mW/m<sub>2</sub>. After temperature decreasing to 4 °C" after converting to JSON, it was transferred to "max power density was 582.4 mW/m. After temperature decreasing to 4 °C"